# Silverlight TargetNullValue binding for Brush dependency property

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a reusable user control with a dependency property which sets the color of a rectangle. The property uses Brush as type.

The data binding works fine, however I would like to add a fallback and null value when the binding has errors or its value is not specified.
Here is my XAML:

```
    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=UnderLineColor, ElementName=Header, 
                              FallbackValue=LightGrey, TargetNullValue=LightGrey}"
               Height="2"
               Margin="0,2"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

And the code of the UnderLineColor DP:

```
    public Brush UnderLineColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(UnderLineColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UnderLineColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UnderLineColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UnderLineColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(SectionHeader), null);
```

The issue is that SL doesn't seem to accept the fallback and nullvalue I specify.

What value should I write into these properties to make it work? Or should I use a ValueConverter instead of this approach?

**Edit:**

Top tip for today: Grey != Gray. Issue is fixed now. :)